# Import HTML to dynamically add elements using JS

Tags: javascript, html, import

I will be dynamically adding elements to my main `index.html` using `.innerHTML += "<p>example</p>";` However I do not want to store the large html-like string in this `.js` file, but instead import it from another file `example.html`

example.html:
`<p>example</p>`

(It is just a snippet of code and not a standalone html file, but I want to keep the `.html` extension for linting, autocompletion and general readability)

My attempts:

`$(...).load('example.html')`: did not work as it replaces of contents of `...` with this example instead of appending it

`import * from example.html`: this and other attempts of importing file failed because of MIME error that text/html cannot be imported

I will be perfectly satisfied with a solution of a method that reads `.html` as text and returns it as a string (preferably not using AJAX or ES6 as I do not feel confident with them). I would then just use the string in `.innerHTML += imported_string;` and call it a day.

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but AJAX might be the best solution here. Besides `$(...).load('example.html')` is also AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want to do, you can use [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to import the content of a file and convert it to text, for example:

```js
function readFile(event) {

  var file = event.target.files[0];

  var stream = new FileReader();
  stream.onload = function(e) {
    var fileContent = e.target.result;
    alert(fileContent);
  }
  stream.readAsText(file);

}

document.getElementById('myFile').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="html" id="myFile">
```

The file input is for presentation purposes, you can easily adapt this to your needs.

You should also perform the customary checks, which I ommited for brevity purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) request to the file that you want to retrieve. This is, in a basic sense, the same way how a browser would request a html file from the server.

The function below sends a request based on what you input as a `file`. For example, `'example.html'`. It then checks if the request was a success and returns the response as a string. The string can then be appended to your `innerHTML`.

```
const getFileAsText = async file => {
  const response = await fetch(file);
  
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Fetching the HTML file went wrong - ${response.statusText}`);
  }

  return response.text();
};
```

You can use it like the example below.

```
getFileAsText('example.html').then(html => {
  document.body.innerHTML += html;
});
```